# gulp-replace для нескольких строк?

Tags: javascript, gulp, сборка

Как можно прописать `pipe` для `gulp-replace` для нескольких js в **gulpfile.js** ?

В **index.html**:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/plagin-1.js"></script>
<script src="js/plagin-2.js"></script>
```

В **gulpfile.js** cейчас так:

```
.pipe(replace('main.js', assets['main.js']))
```

Как сделать замену для всех js файлов, а не для одного main.js?

Comment: Если по простому, то добавить `.pipe(replace('plagin-1.js', assets['plagin-1.js']))` и `.pipe(replace('plagin-2.js', assets['plagin-2.js']))`  (если файлов будет много, то конечно нужен более автоматизированный способ).

Comment: вот про более автоматизированный и хотелось узнать, но видимо для данного плагина нет)

Comment: Можно попробовать такой плагин https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace-assets, он принимает объект, в котором ключи это заменяемые строки, а значения - заменяющие строки. Как раз, то, что дает gulp-hash в assets.json

Comment: Спасибо, помог, все отлично и просто работает!

Comment: Можно звездочку подбросить сюда https://github.com/vladimirgamalian/gulp-replace-assets если помог )

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения. Например вот так:

```
.pipe(replace(/(.{4,8})\.js/g, 'foo'))
```

где:
`.{4,8}` - любой символ от 4 до 8 раз в имени
`\.` - точка
`js` - буквы "j" и "s" в расширении

Больше информации по ссылке: [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace)

Comment: Про регулярные я знаю.
Мне нужно, чтобы совпадали имена - 'main.js', assets['main.js'] !
Так .pipe(replace(/(.{4,8})\.js/g, '/(.{4,8})\.js/g')) же не напишешь )

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, [параметр replacement может быть функцией](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace#replacement)